# What is the correct word for TEMPLE in koine Greek?

Tags: greek, translation-philosophy, temple, ecclesiology

I am currently doing research into the correct understanding between the two Greek words that seem to always be somewhat confused when it comes to translating the words - **Temple** and **Sancruary**.

My current research from multiple sources so far state that when Paul talks about the temple (people as a temple) in his letters he actually doesn't mean temple, but inner sanctuary, or in other words the inner holy place of a temple building.

But any other Greek person that I have asked about this state that it is infact the other way around - ***Hieron*** is the inner holy part of the temple and ***Naos*** is the actual temple building.

***Which translation is correct?***

The bible verses in question -

- 1 Corinthians 3:16 - ***'Naos'*** - Inner Sanctuary
- 1 Corinthians 6:19 - ***'Naos'*** - Inner Sanctuary
- Matthew 4:5 - ***'Hieron'*** - building as temple
- Mark - 11:11 - ***'Hieron'*** - building as temple
- Luke 1:9 - ***'Naos'*** - building as temple
- John 2:14 - ***'Hieron'*** - building as temple
- Acts 2:46 - ***'Hieron'*** - building as temple
- Ephesians 2:21 - ***'Naos'*** - Poeple as Inner Sanctuary
- And the rest of the letters following use - ***'Naos'***

Strong's number 2411 - ***'Hieron'***

**2411** hierón (from 2413 /hierós, "sacred") – the entire Temple complex, i.e. all its enclosures (precincts, courtyards) and the central sanctuary.

Strong's number 3485 - ***'Naos'***

**3485** naós (from naiō, "to dwell") – properly, a sanctuary (divine dwelling-place); a temple (sacred abode), the place of divine manifestation. 3485 (naós) refers to the sanctuary (the Jewish Temple proper), i.e. with just its two inner compartments (rooms). These consisted of

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/66145/whats-the-difference-between-%e1%bc%b1%ce%b5%cf%81%ce%bf%e1%bf%a6-hieron-%ce%bd%ce%b1%e1%bd%b8%ce%bd-naos/66146#66146

Comment: Luke 1:9 'Naos' is the inner sanctuary, including both the Holy of Holies and the adjoining room with the menorah, show bread, etc. Zechariah was serving as a priest.   Only priests could go into that area.  So, Jesus' teachings would be in the outer courtyard areas included in the 'Hieron'.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a summary of extensive entry from BDAG:

**ναός (naos) Temple/Shrine**

> **a place of structure specifically associated with or set apart for a deity, who is frequently perceived to be using it as a dwelling,
> *temple*.**

(a) of temples generally, Acts 17:24, 19:24, etc

(b) of the temple in Jerusalem, (see also LXX 3 Km 6:5, 17; Josephus Ant. 8, 62, etc) The entire temple precinct: Matt 23:17, 35, 27:5, 40, Mark 14:48, 15:29, Luke 1:2, John 2:20, Acts 7:48, Rev 11:2; the Holy of Holies: Matt 27:51, Mark 15:38, Luk 23:45, etc

(c) of the heavenly sanctuary, Rev 14:15, 15:6, 8ab, 16:1, 17, 7:15, 11:19b, 14:17, etc

(d) of the human body or part thereof, 1 Cor 6:19, 3:16, 17, 2 Cor 6:1, Eph 2:21, etc

(e) of Jesus' body, John 2:19-21

**ἱερόν (hieron) Sanctuary/Temple**

[Note: ἱερόν is from the root word meaning "holy" or "priestly"]

(a) of Greeko-Roman temples, Acts 19:27

(b) of the temple in Jerusalem, Matt 12:6, 21:23, 24:1b, Mark 11:27, 12:35, 13:3, Luke 2:46, 20:1, 21:5, John 8:20, 11:56, 18:20, etc

(c) in a general sense, whether polytheistic or monotheistic, 1 Cor 9:13.

Thus, in Koine Greek, the meanings of ναός (naos) and ἱερόν (hieron) overlap but are not identical:

- ναός (naos) means either a temple generally or the Host Holy Place specifically
- ἱερόν (hieron) means either a temple generally or a shrine but **never** refers to the Most Holy Place of the Jerusalem temple.

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Luke 1:9 'Naos' is the inner sanctuary, including both the Holy of Holies and the adjoining room with the menorah, show bread, etc. Zechariah was serving as a priest.   Only priests could go into that area.  So, Jesus' teachings would be in the outer courtyard areas included in the 'Hieron'.

See [What's the difference between ἱεροῦ hieron & ναὸν naos?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/66145/whats-the-difference-between-%e1%bc%b1%ce%b5%cf%81%ce%bf%e1%bf%a6-hieron-%ce%bd%ce%b1%e1%bd%b8%ce%bd-naos/66146#66146)